# Erro ao tentar salvar dados no banco de dados via Java

Tags: java

Estou tentado salvar dados no banco de dados e está retornando o seguinte erro:

> attempt to create merge event with null entity

O *Bean* está assim:

```
public void SalvarCliente(){
try {

ClienteDao clienteDao = new ClienteDao(); 

clienteDao.salvarCliente(cliente);
cliente = new Cliente();
System.out.println("Cliente salvo com sucesso.");
Messages.addGlobalInfo("cliente salvo com sucesso!");

} catch (RuntimeException erro) {
// mensagem de erro para o usuario 
Messages.addGlobalError("ocorreu um erro ao tentar salvar o cliente");
erro.printStackTrace();  
}
}
```

O *XHTML* assim:

```
<h:form id="formCadastro">
<p:panel header="Cadastro" >
<p:panelGrid columns="2" >


<p:outputLabel value="Nome:" />
<p:inputText value="#{clienteBean.cliente.nome}" />

<p:outputLabel value="Telefone:" />
<p:inputText value="#{clienteBean.cliente.telefone}" />

<p:outputLabel value="CPF:" />
<p:inputText value="#{clienteBean.cliente.cpf}" />

<p:outputLabel value="Cidade:" />
<p:inputText value="#{clienteBean.cliente.cidade}" />
<p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{clienteBean.SalvarCliente}" process="@this" />

</p:panelGrid>

</p:panel>
</h:form>
```

**classe Cliente:**

```
@Entity
public class Cliente {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String telefone;
    private String cidade;
    private String cpf;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Cliente other = (Cliente) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: o xhtml assim :
<h:form id="formCadastro">
<p:panel header="Cadastro" >
<p:panelGrid columns="2" >

<p:outputLabel value="Nome:" />
<p:inputText value="#{clienteBean.cliente.nome}" />

<p:outputLabel value="Telefone:" />
<p:inputText value="#{clienteBean.cliente.telefone}" />
<p:outputLabel value="CPF:" />
<p:inputText value="#{clienteBean.cliente.cpf}" />

<p:outputLabel value="Cidade:" />
<p:inputText value="#{clienteBean.cliente.cidade}" />



<p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{clienteBean.SalvarCliente}" process="@this" />
</p:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
</h:form>

Comment: Como está a classe `Cliente`? Você está usando algum ORM como Hibernate?

Comment: estou sim, Entity
public class Cliente {
 Id
 GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;etc...

Comment: Coloque no texto da pergunta esse classe

Comment: coloquei , acredito que o problema seja o meu xhtml, fiz um outro com layout com oncomplete="PF('dialogo').show();" e widgetVar="dialogo" e funcionou normalmente

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se sua classe Cliente está anotada com @Entity.
Se ela possui uma variável anotada com @Id e @GeneratedValue

Como no exemplo da documentação:
[@GeneratedValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html)

Comment: esta sim. tem o entity , o id e o generateValue